# Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $resourseProvider <- $resourse <- Phone Angular factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having problem while injecting resource.

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $resourseProvider <- $resourse <- Phone

This is my code

**index.html**

```
     <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
     <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>  
     <script src="core/phone.module.js"></script>
     <script src="core/phone.factory.js"></script>
     <script src="phone-list/phone-list.module.js"></script>
     <script src="phone-list/phone-list.component.js"></script>
     <script src="app.module.js"></script>
```

**app.module.js**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('phoneApp', [
  'phoneList',  
  'getphone'
]);
```

**phone-list.module.js**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('phoneList', ['getphone']);
```

**phone-list.component.js**

```
'use strict';

angular.
module('phoneList').
component('phoneList', {
  templateUrl: 'phone-list/phone-list.template.html',
  controller: ['$http', '$scope', 'Phone',
  function PhoneListController($http, $scope, Phone){
    var self = this;
    $scope.search = {};
    .....
```

**phone.module.js**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('getphone', ['ngResource']);
```

**phone.factory.js**

```
'use strict';

angular.
module('getphone').
factory('Phone', ['$resourse',
  function($resourse) {
    return $resourse('phone/:phoneId.json', {}, {
      query: {
        methode: 'GET',
        params: {phoneId: 'phones'},
        isArray: true
      }
    });
  }
  ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is simple. You have spelled the word `resource` incorrectly in **phone.factory.js**

```
'use strict';
angular.
module('getphone').
factory('Phone', ['$resourse',  // should be resource
  function($resourse) {
    return $resourse('phone/:phoneId.json', {}, {
      query: {
        methode: 'GET',
        params: {phoneId: 'phones'},
        isArray: true
      }
    });
  }
]);
```

Comment: Oh... Yes. Thanks